# Symbolic combinations

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have 3 lists: `{a,a},{b,b},{c,c}`, then the desired output is

```
{{a,b c}, {a b,c}, {a c,b}, 
{a a,b c}, {a a b,c}, {a a c,b}, 
{a,b b c}, {a b b,c}, {a c,b b}, 
{a,b c c}, {a b,c c}, {a c c,b}, 
{a a,b b c}, {a a b b,c}, {a a c,b b}, 
{a,b b c c}, {a b b,c c}, {a c c,b b}, 
{a a,b c c}, {a a b,c c}, {a a c,b b}, 
{a a,b b c c}, {a a b b,c c},{a a c c,b b}}
```

This gets some of the way there

```
list = SetPartitions[{a, a, b, b, c, c}];
list1 = DeleteDuplicates@
Flatten[{DeleteDuplicates@
  Take[Table[Times @@ Rest[list][[n, 1]], {n, 1, Length@list}], 
   Length@list - 1], 
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Take[Table[Times @@ Rest[list][[n, 2]], {n, 1, Length@list}], 
   Length@list - 1]}];
Transpose[{list1, Reverse@list1}]
```

but there are some anomalies.

This does it (I think)

```
{Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a, b, c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a a, b, c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a a, b b, c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a a, b b, c c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a , b b, c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a , b b, c c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a a, b , c c}],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a a, b b, c }],
Most@Rest@SetPartitions[{a a, b b, c c}]}
```

but I'm not sure if it works for larger sets - eg `{a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d,d,d}`, and I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing it.

## Update

For larger set:

`{a,b c d}
{a a, b c d}
{a a c, b b d d}`

are all OK, but

`{a, a b c d}`

is not, because `a` is in parts 1 and part two of the pair.

Also,

`{b,c d d}`

isn't, because not all elements `a,b,c,d` are included.

```
list2 = {c^2, a^2, b^2, c, a, b};
list3 = DeleteDuplicates@
Sort@Flatten@Table[list2[[i]]*list2[[j]], {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, i - 1}];
Transpose[{list3, Reverse@list3}]
```

Is another attempt - not going too well here :/

Comment: Could you give few elements of the desired output for a larger set (a,b,c,d) ? Still pairs ? For example: {a,bcd} ? but not {a,bdc} ? not {bcd,a} ? Right ?

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks for the interest, please see update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Update to take into account any "power" and list size as requested.

Here you just define what you want :

```
list = {a, b, c};
power=3;
```

Then just run these steps :

```
replist = Table[{# -> #^i}, {i, power}] & /@ list;
s1 = Subsets[Rest@list][[1 ;; -2]];
s2 = {Join[{First@list}, #], Complement[Rest@list, #]} & /@ s1;
res = Fold[ReplaceAll, s2, replist] // Flatten[#, Length@list] &
```

gives here

[image]

or if you prefer :

```
(Times @@@ #) & /@ res
```

[image]

### Original post

Here is a solution in 2 steps.

**1.** I think that first the most important is to form all the pair combinations including only the single letters (a not aa, b not bb, ...). This can be achieved with `Subsets`.

```
list={b,c};
s1 = Subsets[list][[1 ;; -2]]
s2 = {Join[{a}, #], Complement[list, #]} & /@ s1
```

gives

```
{{}, {b}, {c}}
{{{a}, {b, c}}, {{a, b}, {c}}, {{a, c}, {b}}}
```

`s2`contains already the correct "shape" of the final solution : if you replace `a` by `aa` (`b` by `bb`, etc ...) you notice that the lists are part of the solutions. You just need to form all possible substitutions ...

**2.** This can be achieved with :

```
res = Fold[{#, ReplaceAll[##]} &, s2, {a -> aa, b -> bb, c -> cc}] // Flatten[#, Length@list+1] &
```

gives

[image]

---

Application for the subset {a,b,c,d} :

```
list = {b, c, d};
s1 = Subsets[list][[1 ;; -2]]
s2 = {Join[{a}, #], Complement[list, #]} & /@ s1
res = Fold[{#, ReplaceAll[##]} &, s2, {a -> aa, b -> bb, c -> cc, d -> dd}] // Flatten[#, Length@list + 1] &
```

gives the following steps :

[image]

Comment: this is great!! Thank you very much - will have a play now :)

Comment: If I wanted to go to higher powers of `a,b,c,d`, is that possible? eg- `a->aaaa` , etc?

Comment: this works really wel :) - Would it be possible to add an extra exponent `a -> aaa`?

Comment: @martin Please see my update.

Comment: the update is great - works really well - thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[f2];
Join @@ (With[{k = #}, (Times @@@ {Complement[k, #], #}) & /@ Subsets[k, {2}]] & /@ 
          Tuples[{#1, Times@##} & @@@ #]) &;

f2@{{a, a}, {b, b}, {c, c}}
```

[image]

```
f2@{{a, a, a, a}, {b, b, b, b}, {c, c, c, c}}
```

[image]

```
f2@{{a, a}, {b, b}, {c, c}, {d, d}}
```

[image]

---

**Original  post:**

```
ClearAll[f1];
f1 = With[{k = #}, Times @@@ SortBy[#, First] & /@ ({Complement[k, #], #} & /@ Subsets[k, {2}])] &;

list = {{a, a}, {b, b}, {c, c}};
nlist = {#1, HoldForm[Times@##]} & @@@ list;
f1 /@ Tuples[nlist] // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

```
list = {{a, a}, {b, b}, {c, c}, {d, d}};
nlist = {#1, HoldForm[Times@##]} & @@@ list;
f1 /@ Tuples[nlist] // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

Comment: this is fantastic! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @martin, my pleasure. I was worried that you wanted the final list in a specific order. Can we assume that ordering of elements does not matter?

Comment: doesn't matter at all :)

Comment: If I try
`list = {Table[a, {x, 1, exp}], Table[b, {x, 1, exp}], 
   Table[c, {x, 1, exp}], Table[d, {x, 1, exp}], 
   Table[e, {x, 1, exp}], Table[f, {x, 1, exp}], 
   Table[g, {x, 1, exp}], Table[h, {x, 1, exp}]};
nlist = {#1, Times@##} & @@@ list;
Take[ff /@ Tuples[nlist], 10]`
it seems to jump straight to 4th power. Is there any way of keeping lower powers in there?

Comment: note - I changed `f` to `ff` to accomodate new `f`

Comment: martin, try `Take[Join@@(ff/@Tuples[nlist]),10]`.

Comment: exp: exponent. Will give your suggestion a go now :)

Comment: thank you very much for your update, but I am really looking for something that catches all of the exponents in a range as per SquareOne's update, where for exp=3, power two components are also considered